# How to insert multiple keys in a pkcs12 keystore with `openssl pkcs12`?

Tags: openssl, keystore, keytool

With the Java keytool I can add multiple keys in the pkcs12 keystore:

```
keytool -genkeypair -alias foo -keyalg rsa  -dname "CN=Foo, OU=..., O=..., L=..., C=..."  -storetype pkcs12  -keystore keystore.p12

keytool -genkeypair -alias bar -keyalg rsa  -dname "CN=Bar, OU=..., O=..., L=..., C=..."  -storetype pkcs12  -keystore keystore.p12
```

How does one do this with `openssl pkcs12`?